# Problemas con rutas laravel Register

Tags: laravel-5

Buen dia

He realizado pruebas con el sistema auth  que trae por defecto laravel 5.5,
inicialmente el trate el register en la portada principal para luego iniciar
sesion, pero yo no quiero el register en la portada principal, asi que despues de iniciar session puse un panel, alli situe el register, pero no he podido hacer que
redireccione correctamente ya que la solicitud pasa al middleware y se queda redirigiendo, el navegador me da este error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

La unica diferencia es que el register ya no esta en la portada principal como lo trae laravel, si no que esta adentro despues de iniciar session.

middleware RedirectifAuthenticated https://paste.laravel.io/e999c8ae-925c-4b3d-a55e-82913b20ac40

rutas auth https://paste.laravel.io/a77e6800-049d-4eb6-942d-9529b1b7b4a2#

RegisterController

https://paste.laravel.io/169a87ee-ad02-4b49-86b6-534de50cec2a.

Donde ubique el register, sobre el boton crear cuenta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y por que no haces tu mismo crud para usuarios?
Usas rutas Resource creas un controlador UserController con los respectivos métodos, así podrás usar ese controller Para manejar usuarios de tu sistema.

Comment: Muy bien, hare lo que dices, en base a eso tengo una duda, puedo incluir el metodo showregistrationform del controlador registercontroller, en otro controlador que yo quiera?